# How to get this sql code to work in google big query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, lucidchart

This code is taken from lucidchart and would like to run it in gbq to get the dataset information.

```
SELECT 'mysql' dbms,t.TABLE_SCHEMA,t.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME,c.ORDINAL_POSITION,c.DATA_TYPE,c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,n.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,k.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA,k.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON t.TABLE_SCHEMA=c.TABLE_SCHEMA AND t.TABLE_NAME=c.TABLE_NAME LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k ON c.TABLE_SCHEMA=k.TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.TABLE_NAME=k.TABLE_NAME AND c.COLUMN_NAME=k.COLUMN_NAME LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS n ON k.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA=n.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA AND k.CONSTRAINT_NAME=n.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND k.TABLE_SCHEMA=n.TABLE_SCHEMA AND k.TABLE_NAME=n.TABLE_NAME WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN('INFORMATION_SCHEMA','mysql','performance_schema');
```

The error message is: Table name "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to query this is to add the prefix the dataset to the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view. [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view)

Example from doc

```sql
SELECT
 * EXCEPT(is_generated, generation_expression, is_stored, is_updatable)
FROM
 `bigquery-public-data`.census_bureau_usa.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
 table_name="population_by_zip_2010"
```